# What are the reward levels for the Arena?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile

Currently between each reward level there only seems to be a bar saying how far along you have progressed. And how far till the next reward, for example, between challenger 1 and challenger 2.

What are the gaps between each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge of the arena, the intervals between ranks are based on player ranks and their amount of arena points, I do not know any solid numbers due to the fact Netherrealm hasn't shown any sort of numbers for the ranks. The main reason I believe the ranks are based off of player points and not set values is because after a short period of time not running arena I noticed my rank dropped two ranks while I wasn't fighting.

If Netherrealm ever releases any sort of solid numbers on what ranks represent on the leaderboard I will update this answer to reflect that.

Comment: Ahh that actually makes sense, so probably correct. A bit annoying how it seems the top of the leader board looks to either be full of people hackers or people spending an insane amount of money then.

Comment: I haven't honestly been gunning for top ranks getting to elite isn't too hard with a few teams for arena. As long as you have a few teams you should be fine.

Comment: Oh I haven't either but still annoying because it means a "normal" player will never make it into the top N players.

Comment: Honestly by the looks of the rewards right now from the Arena it won't be as big of a deal as it was in Injustice 1 where the top 5% of players could get extremely powerful heroes nobody else could. Instead it just being credits, gems, and Arena Tokens.